# Django Dynamic models throws programming error

Tags: python-3.x

I use django-dynamic-model 0.1.0 for dynamic modelling in django.

I have already tried reverting the migrations, changing db. But nothing seems to work.

models.py:

```
from dynamic_models.models import AbstractModelSchema, AbstractFieldSchema

class ModelSchema(AbstractModelSchema):
    pass


class FieldSchema(AbstractFieldSchema):
    pass
```

views.py:

```
car_model_schema = ModelSchema.objects.create(name='Car')
```

I face error while creating ModelSchema object:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1.0/boilerplate_apps/graph/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubox72/Extras/graph/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "dynamic_models_modelfieldschema" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ynamic_models_modelfieldschema"."max_length" FROM "dynamic_m...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubox72/Extras/graph/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  .......
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "dynamic_models_modelfieldschema" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ynamic_models_modelfieldschema"."max_length" FROM "dynamic_m...
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying running this migration as well

```
python manage.py makemigrations dynamic_models
```

And then,

```
python manage.py migrate dynamic_models
```

This should solve this issue.